# Amazon API Gateway User keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I have an API deployed on AWS API Gateway. I will have multiple subscribers using my API and each customer would be unique. Is it possible that each customer will have a separate API key unique to him? Or will I have to create those many IAM users in order for them to be unique? If yes for the IAM users, then what is the upper limit of the number of users? I will be doing all this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

By unique, if you mean that you should be able to identify which request came from who, then you can generate one API Key per subscriber. You can generate up to 10000 API keys per AWS account. More details about API keys [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-api-keys.html).

By unique, if you mean that each subscriber should have access to a unique set of API resources/methods/stages, then you can create different IAM roles with different levels of permissions and let the subscribers assume the roles. You can create up to 250 roles per account. More details about access permissions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/permissions.html).

Comment: For each user to have different throttle, does he/she need to have different api keys? My app have more than 1000 users, but the maximum number allowed per region is only 500. So, can I use API gateway for my app?

Comment: Adding this comment for those who come across this via search in the future: you can have more than 500 users/API keys. You will need to open a support request (or use the Serice Quota console https://docs.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/latest/userguide/intro.html) with AWS to ask for them to increase the limit. Documentation suggests the upper limit is 10,000 keys per gateway.