# Amazon API security with API Keys?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have deployed my rest API on amazon API gateway and I have a scenario in front of me with security concern.
I am using an api key for all the api requests, I wanna know if the that api key is exposed somehow and as we know the same api key is being used by already published apps...Then what are my options?

Also as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37409854/amazon-api-gateway-user-keys/37423971#37423971)
I can have only 10000 API keys per AWS account if I want the api keys to be unique per user for it to be more secure but what if the number of user shoots out to be more than 10000.
Please suggest on the same as it is very important.

Comment: i'm not sure the the 'api keys' that your describing should be used for the public.... i think you need to look into your app design. but then again. i havent used api gateway.....

Comment: I just want to know how aws secures api with api-keys as anyone can make the request with api keys if exposed?

Comment: How do you propose assigning api-keys to users? You probably need to look into API Gateway Custom Authorizers.

Comment: I don't believe there is any way to secure an API that uses keys other than by keeping the key private. It's like saying "How can I keep my door locked if I lose my house key?" A key is a key is a key.

You may want to look into other authorization methods if this is important for your application.

Comment: esperluette is correct. The API key should be the first part of a larger authorization scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API keys are not recommended for authorization. Calls received from each API key are monitored and included in the Amazon CloudWatch Logs you can enable for each stage. You should use API keys to monitor usage by third-party developers and leverage a stronger mechanism for authorization, such as IAM or [custom authorizers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html).

Hope this helps

Comment: I am going through the docs  but unable to understand How is lambda function associated with my api methods and how does it work?

Comment: I have been reading the docs whole day but I am really not sure how lamda works and I have api deployed as HTTP Proxy, can you please suggest how do I make it secure?

Comment: If I set Authorization from NONE to AWS_IAM in Method Request pane and HTTP header in integration to 'method.request.header.Authorization' then what I should be passing in header as authorization? I wanna know if I can secure HTTP proxy api by any means